# Formal interpretation of likelihood ratio tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The following is a hypothetical question and I don't have a specific model in mind...

Consider two models $M_0, M_1$ such that $M_0$ is nested within $M_1$.

I perform the likelihood ratio test with $M_0$ being considered the "null" model and obtain a test statistic $\chi$. I understand that *if* the null model $M_0$ is true, then asymptotically $\chi$ will follow a chi-square distribution with $k_1 - k_0$ degrees of freedom, the difference in parameters between the two models.

What I'm having trouble understanding is how to actually interpret a rejection.

So suppose $\chi$ is such that we obtain a very small p-value and reject the null hypothesis.

What does this actually mean with respect to the model $M_1$? Does it actually tell us anything about whether it is a good fit?

Aren't we simply rejecting that the null model is true, so that it only tells us the model $M_0$ is unlikely to hold, and does not tell us anything about the validity of $M_1$?

The reason I am confused is that many examples use the likelihood ratio test in order to *compare* the two models. But how does this test tell us about the comparitive fit, rather than simply "$M_0$ does not hold"?

Hopefully I've made my confusion clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are assessing whether or not M1 provides a statistically better fit than M0, that’s all. It does not indicate whether or not M0 (or M1 for that matter) is a *good* fit. You can imagine a situation where your models are misspecified such that neither would be considered ‘good’, but because M1 slightly leads to lower error, it is significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following special case.
Assume model $M_1$ is sufficiently flexible and
Contains the distribution which generated the data.
In addition, assume
$M_0$ is fully nested within $M_1$, then
rejecting the null hypothesis that 
$M_1$ and $M_0$ provide equally good fits implies
That $M_0$ is not a good fit for the class of
statistical environments specified by $M_1$.
So in this very special case where $M_1$ is very flexible
The likelihood ratio test is detecting lack of fit
In model $M_0$.